# Flexbox items internal size ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm beginning my self-studying on web development. Currently working out on JS and trying to create a little "etch-a-sketch" app. I wrote a code which creates canvas with predefined "pixel" size. It work's fine to me. However, in order to make script file as narrow as possible I'm wondering if I can set size properties of pixels entirely by Flexbox properties in CSS. Mathematically speaking I'd like every new element inside parent container to have properties: Width = parentsWidth/nthChild, Height = Width  (so every item could always be the biggest possible square regardless of items number).

```js
let initialValue = 100;
const radioValues = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=size]');
let pixelSize = initialValue;

// event listener for chosing size value and setting new canvas
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  radioValues[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    initialValue = Number((e.target.value));
    pixelSize = initialValue;

    //erasing existing pixels
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.pixel').length > 0) {
      const existingPixel = document.querySelectorAll('.pixel')

      for(let i = 0; i < existingPixel.length;i++){
        existingPixel[i].remove();
      }
    }
    // building new pixels
    for (let i = 0; i < pixelSize; i++){
      let container = document.querySelector('.container');
      let pixel = document.createElement('div');
      pixel.setAttribute('class', 'pixel');

      // part to get rid of
      if (pixelSize == 400) {
        pixel.style.height = "25px";
        pixel.style.width = "25px";
      }

      if (pixelSize == 1600) {
        pixel.style.height = "12.5px";
        pixel.style.width = "12.5px";
      }

      container.appendChild(pixel);
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
}

.pixel {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="size_selection" type="radio" name="size" value="100" checked> <label for="size_selection">10x10</label>
  <input class="size_selection" type="radio" name="size" value="400"> <label for="size_selection">20x20</label>
  <input class="size_selection" type="radio" name="size" value="1600"> <label for="size_selection">40x40</label>
</form>
<div class="container"></div>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just refactored your script to use css grid and the corresponding `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns` properties to match your grid.

Using grid in this instance makes it much more easy to get the result you want.

Just look around, I made some changes not only to CSS but also to HTML and JS. Hope it helps

```js
let initialValue = 100;
const radioValues = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=size]');
let pixelSize = initialValue;
let container = document.getElementById('container');

// event listener for chosing size value and setting new canvas
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  radioValues[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    initialValue = Number((e.target.value));
    pixelSize = initialValue;

    //erasing existing pixels
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.pixel').length > 0) {
      const existingPixel = document.querySelectorAll('.pixel')

      for (let i = 0; i < existingPixel.length; i++) {
        existingPixel[i].remove();
      }
    }
    // building new pixels
    // setting the correct number of columns and rows in the grid
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(' + pixelSize + ', 1fr)';
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = 'repeat(' + pixelSize + ', 1fr)';

    for (let i = 0; i < pixelSize * pixelSize; i++) {
      let pixel = document.createElement('div');
      pixel.classList.add('pixel');
      container.appendChild(pixel);
    }
  })
}

radioValues[0].click();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 2rem auto;
}

#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: grid;
}

.pixel {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input class="size_selection" type="radio" name="size" value="10" checked> <label for="size_selection">10x10</label>
    <input class="size_selection" type="radio" name="size" value="20"> <label for="size_selection">20x20</label>
    <input class="size_selection" type="radio" name="size" value="40"> <label for="size_selection">40x40</label>
  </form>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</body>
```

Comment: If you think I answered your question, please consider accepting this answer as the correct one, so that others having similar problems can easily find it.